# Javascript to be used as bookmarklet changing entire source

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to adjust the look of yahoo's ff page with a bookmarklet.  So I wrote the following script

```
javascript:var lst = document.getElementsByClassName('Mod');for(var i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {lst[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(about:blank)'};
```

Which replaces the entire source with "about:blank"  What it's supposed to do is remove the backgroundimage for certain sections.

Here is the page I'm trying to update.

http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the *JavaScript* needs to evaluate to *undefined*, otherwise `document.open` will be called and the page set to the final output.

Just add an `undefined;` on the very end.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first bookmarklet.  Your fix works perfectly, and I appreciate the explanation.

Comment: I would advise a different, saner fix. Simply wrap your code inside a function and call it: `javascript:(function(){ /* your code here */ })();`